# How to make an image class which renders multiple images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Sorry for my bad English I am also fairly new to React (just started yesterday)

but I would like to know how we can render a variable number of images like if I specify the no of images with an array specifying the file names it should render all the images

like is a there

```
array = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
arrLen = array.length

render(
<MultipleImage 
    noOfImage = { arrLen}
    fileName = arrayOfFileNames
/>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [map](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to map over an array and render the image. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dew-qz67l?file=/src/App.js)

In this example I've used [picsum](https://picsum.photos/) to simulate the source.

It would be better to create a new **Image** component so that you can use it again.

```
function Image({ fileName }) {
  return (
    <img  src={fileName}/>
  )
}

function App() {
  const array = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
  render(
    <>
      {
        array.map( image => {
          return (
            <Image fileName = { image }/>
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map() method to iterate the array of images.
In this examle, I have passed the images[] array as a Prop to Image List component and in Image List component use the map method to itterate over all images.

[Code Sandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-montalcini-ew83y?file=/src/App.js)

App.js Component

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        images: ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
        <ImageList images={this.state.images}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Image List Component

```
const ImageList = (props) => {

    const images = props.images.map((image) => {
        return <img src={image} alt={image} />
    });
   return <div className="image-list">{images}</div>

}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array map() method to loop the image source array and pass the single element of the array to the react component through props. here is an example.
N.B: "you should learn about map(), and how to pass props in components"

```
    function Image(props) {
  return (
    <img  src={props.source}/>
  )
}

function App() {
  const images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
  render(
    <>
      {
        images.map( img => 
          (
              <Image source = { img }/>
          )
      }
    </>
  );
}
```