# What's the best way to show multiple static images in a React app?

Tags: reactjs

I've just started to learn React. I've zero experience so go easy.

I have 4 images that I want to display horizontally across my app.

I know I can just do

```
import Image1 from './Image1.png` 
import Image2 from './Image2.png`
...
```

And then within my app.js I can add something like

```
<Col> 
  <img src ...> 
</Col>
<Col> 
  <img src ...> 
</Col>
```

I've looked at the documentation and can't really find the correct way. What's the best way to avoid creating `<Col> </Col>` for every image?

Hope this makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: If you're wondering how to loop over a list, that's [well documented](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple images on React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922587/import-multiple-images-on-react)_

Comment: Or this? [How to make an image class which renders multiple images in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363008/how-to-make-an-image-class-which-renders-multiple-images-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create new component to contain `col` and `img` called `imageWrapper`

```
function ImageWrapper({src}) {
  return <Col> 
     <img src={src}> 
    </Col>
}
```

then use it

```
<ImageWrapper src...>
<ImageWrapper src...>
```

also you can use array for images then use `map`
like this

```js
import Image1 from './Image1.png' 
import Image2 from './Image2.png'
const arrayImage=[ Image1 , Image1 ]

return arrayImage.map((image)=>{
   return (
       <Col> 
        <img src={image}> 
       </Col>
      )
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, what I am trying to avoid is writing `<img =`  x4  and maybe cycling through an array of images? Like a for loop?

Comment: @JacksWastedLife I update my answer added map loop example

Answer (score 0):

```
{[img1, img2....].map((image, i) => (
  <Col key={i}>
    <img src={image} />
  </Col>
)}
```

this is an easy/correct way to do it